# What are the limits and restrictions for new users?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, new-users

In the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), it is not clear that there is a rep limit before a new user can post URLs. This may lead some people to believe that a newcomer without rep is forgetting linking URLs, may result in unnecessary downvotes or rude comments.

While I think this limit is a good measure to prevent spam, I believe it must be documented. I personally learned it from a comment to a "linkless" answer.

> #### Related: [How does "Reputation" work on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow)
>
> Documents the reasons for the gains and losses of reputation but not the limitations.

Comment: Drats to the double whammy mod tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main restrictions for low-reputation users are:

- [Users with less than 10 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) may only link two URL per post
- Users with less than 50 rep may not [leave comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) except on their own post or answers to their question
- Users with less than 125 rep may only post one question every 20 minutes and one answer every 3 minutes

To lift these restrictions, gain more rep!

See [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) for more details.

Comment: What if they have a by on the use of example.com? Might help them better explain without opening it up for spamming.

Comment: New users really should be only able to post one question a DAY. To limit it only to one every 20 minutes sends the message that it's okay to ask lots of questions in rapid succession. Heck, it should take more than 20 minutes to ask a thoughtful question in any case.

Comment: @Ether When first encountering the site, one can be tempted to solve long-standing doubts, which does not mean one is is unexperienced or asking her job to be done.

Comment: In addition to this, [new users (less than 15 rep) cannot mark their questions as community wiki when they initially ask them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49745/why-cant-i-mark-a-question-as-community-wiki-on-so-when-asking-it/49748#49748).

Comment: Can we make it so that a "new" user is someone with less than 100 rep? It's not hard to gain 15 rep and then become a spammer.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it is 10 rep to post a link in your post if you are a new user. I have gone and given up votes to new users precisely for the reason to allow them to post URL's (they had come into the chat room to inquire, and after explaining themselves and reading their question I felt they were deserved an opportunity to post the URLs).