# how to lift ban from answering any topic

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

If any of us find ourselves facing difficulty or problems in submitting an answer for any question asked in StackOverflow and you are getting this message `"answer from your account is banned"` then please see below, as it should be as helpful for you as it was for me.

This will be ended we earn a minimum of 10 reputation. As their are certain restrictions on new users for answering any questions randomly, this will be lifted asap once you get 10 reputation.

Question: **If you have restrictions on answering questions, how are you supposed to be able to ever earn this 10 minimum reputation?**

Comment: you need to answer the questions that are being posted and get upvotes. As u would get upvotes your rating/reputation will improve and you will gain be allowed to answer questions. but there is as such no limit specified as to how many answers you need to give or how many reputation you need to earn so start answering questions and increase reputation

Comment: that is the problem i am not able to give answer at any post!!!!!!!

Comment: @NetStarter please see me edited  question as i mentioned there how it is different to that question..

Comment: @LoveGarg What on earth is this edit you've just made? Are you answering your own question right there? That's not what questions are for.

Comment: thanks @bart actually mistakenly i overwrite the question thanks again

Comment: @LoveGarg i had marked it as duplicate based on the question you asked *before the edits were made*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as you keep editing your question with points that don't make sense or appears as if you are trying to answer your own question, I am going to try to respond to points in your question and also some comments you have made.

---

> Its will be ended as we get min. 10 reputation. As their is certain restriction on new user for answering any question randomly while this will be lifted asap you get 10 reputation..

and

> hey friends its their policy as they not allowing 10 reputation user to answer the questions frequently thanks @Seidr

If I am reading both of these statements correctly, you are trying to say that Stack Overflow does not permit users with 10 rep to answer as a matter of policy.  This is simply untrue.  Anyone can answer.  There are [restrictions on new users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) with less than 125 reputation that rate-limit them so they cannot post too many answers in a short period of time (no more than 1 answer in 3 minutes per [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4578/182513))

As is mentioned in [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers), the  ban is automatic and the only way to lift it is automatic as well.  The only way to lift the ban is to improve your existing content and to contribute in other ways.

The exact criteria for the ban algorithm are unpublished, so no one exactly know what it will take to lift the ban, but based on comments from the developers and educated guesses from users throughout the years, improving existing content is the most important, especially posts that were deleted within the 30 days of being posted.  You need to edit your answers so they attract upvotes, or at least get the downvotes retracted.

Looking at your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2314169/love-garg?tab=answers), you only have 2 undeleted answers, both with zero score.  Given that, it seems likely that you have deleted content, either self-deletes or posts deleted by a moderator.  If you have deleted answers, it is necessary to flag one of your existing posts with a custom flag and ask a moderator to undelete your answers so you can improve them.

---

> i have checked the link but not found suitable in my case as i have not deleted any question or answer ever and never get negative rating

Forgive me, but this seems unlikely, not because I don't believe you, but because there are dozens of (now deleted) examples of a banned user claiming in a MSO post that they don't have any deleted content, only for them to end up having 4 or 5 deleted posts.

However, if it is true that you do not have deleted answers then be sure to read [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) completely as the very last item could possibly apply:

> ### My account is in good standing how come I still get banned?
>
> Since the ban is based on IP address as well, when you browse from a shared computer or from work location that give the same IP address to many end users it's enough that one get banned and all others are "banned" as well. To rectify this, just browse from a different location.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer, which is to a similar question as to clarity regarding bans / suspensions on StackExchange sites.

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Basically, you need to contribute to the site in ways other than answering questions. That's what I took away from that answer, anyway.

Other ways to contribute - I'm guessing - would be asking questions which get up voted by others (aka useful questions which others may need the answer to), editing prior answers so that they get up voted, to negate the down vote effect on them, or by reporting abusive / off topic questions / answers / comments.

The more you interact with StackExchange sites, the more you will be viewed as a legitimate source of information. Interact as much as you can (usefully, I might add..don't just up vote - or down vote everything you see. comment, give reasons) with the site(s).

Comment: i have checked the link but not found suitable in my case as i have not deleted any question or answer ever and never get negative rating

Comment: In that case, all I can suggest is contacting StackOverflow (this is mentioned in the linked answer I provided above) and asking for further clarification regarding your ban (search for 'If you really, really think the ban is an error' on that answer I linked to).

Comment: Perhaps try improving the quality of your questions, accepting answers (or where incorrect answers have been provided due to a misunderstanding of the question, clarifying the question), or up voting responses. After looking at your activity, that's the only reason I can see for you being banned - unless you actually have deleted questions / answers that have been down voted, as I imagine they'd still be taken into account.

Comment: well thanks thinking if something simpler is there or possible,
thanks again for you solution

Comment: You're welcome - as an example as to how you can interact more with StackOverflow, if you believe this answered your question, accept / up vote it. If you just found the answer useful, or insightful (but did not answer your question) up vote it. Validating others responses to questions is an important part of the StackExchange sites.

Comment: notable to up vote as voting require minimum 15 reputation and as its not proper answer to my question i can't accept it.
Well thanks for your support.

Comment: How is it not a proper answer? You've asked how to get a ban removed, and if you are not sure as to why you have been banned, the last option is to contact StackOverflow. There is NO easy way to remove a ban, other than interacting further with the StackExchange sites.

Comment: hey friends its their policy as they not allowing 10 reputation user to answer the questions frequently thanks @Seidr

Comment: @LoveGarg No, the question ban's exact rules are secret but getting lots of downvotes/deleted questions is the usual cause, actual rep is of low/no importance. If you really have no deleted/downvoted questions then; do you share your IP with anyone else. It could be a question ban on the IP you're using

Comment: @RichardTingle you are correct but in some cases when you are new then this rule implies..

Comment: @LoveGarg What rule? That you're answer banned for having low reputation? Then no one would ever get anywhere because we all had low rep once. It may stop you posting **many many** answers per day, but thats much more than the 2 answers you have

Comment: @RichardTingle there is not any specific per day rule exist and having some amount of answer's is greeted as i don't know it before

Comment: @LoveGarg I'm struggling to understand what you're saying

Comment: @RichardTingle i want to say as a new comer i don't know about all these things so i am sharing these things for others. Because i was shocked that time so i want nobody will get any shock from these types of happening

Comment: @LoveGarg but how are the new user restrictions (specifically the rate-limiting on answering) even remotely related to getting a answer ban?  Besides, the rated limiting on new users is very small.  1 answer in 3 minutes is fair.  It takes longer than that to write a proper answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 i don't know about it

Comment: @LoveGarg Presumably a message came up stating that you were answering too fast and should slow down?

Comment: @LoveGarg: What happened was that you got an upvote, which released you from the ban (since the ban is based on upvotes and downvotes). That upvote *also* put you above 10 reputation. There is *not* a rule that people with <10 rep cannot answer or that having 10 rep frees you. *Many* people with more than 10 rep get banned (and come here to ask about it).